# Can't remote into a computer because "the remote computer requires Network Authentication"

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop

I'm trying to remote into one Windows 7 computer from another Windows 7 computer, and am getting this error:

> The remote computer requires Network Level Authentication, which your computer does not support

[image: Screenshot of error]

I believe my computer *does* support Network Level Authentication, because:

1. I'm on Windows 7
2. I have remoted into the target computer from this computer before, with Network Level Authentication required on the target computer
3. The "About" dialog of mstsc.exe says that it is supported:

[image: Screenshot of About dialog]

Has anyone seen this issue before, or know how I can fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like settings were changed on the remote computer, not yours.

The easiest way to go around this, although not as safe, is to to enable "Allow connections from computer running any version of Remote Desktop (less secure)"

It is found in System Properties <kbd>Win + Pause/Break</kbd> -> Advanced system settings -> Remote.

Should you not want to allow login to computers without NLA, let me know and we'll sort it out.

Comment: _I use Windows 10 x64 to connect to Windows Server 2012._
`Using Remote Desktop (mstsc) is OK connected`

`Using "Terminals" https://github.com/Terminals-Origin/Terminals for connect using RDP protocol`, I get that error.

***I NOT want change remote computer, ONLY local computer.***

Answer (score 7):

In my case, it was a problem with a custom RDP file we were using, and also seemed to affect our Windows 10 remote hosts, but not our Windows 7 remote hosts.

The solution was to edit the .RDP file in a text editor and change `enablecredsspsupport:i:0` to `enablecredsspsupport:i:1` or deleting the line altogether.  It didn't seem to matter whether or not requiring Network Level Authentication was enabled on the remote Windows 10 host.

Comment: This was it for me - I had edited my %userprofile%\documents\Default.rdp file and added enablecredsspsupport:i:0 for testing other RDP connections. I had to remove that line.

Comment: This was also it for me. I set `enablecredssupport:i:1` and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Our problem was caused by a corrupted crypto database catalog:

Solution

- Stop Cryptographic Services (cryptsvc) by running "net stop
  cryptsvc".
- Delete or rename the C:\Windows\System32\catroot2 folder.
- Start cryptsvc by running "net start cryptsvc".
- Restart the computer.
- C:\Windows\System32\catroot2 will be recreated.
- Wait for all the catalog files from C:\Windows\System32\catroot to be
  imported into the catroot2 database. This may take up to an hour, so
  be patient.

Comment: Was this on the client side, or on the server side?

Comment: I followed your steps and its been 20 min now, Cannot see catroot2 folder in System32/. There is total of 45MB of data in C:\Windows\System32\catroot. and how come it will take upto an hour to copy ?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the computer cert, then requesting a new computer cert fixed the issue for me.

- MMC
- Add Snap-In (Certificates, Computer, Local Computer)
- Certificates -> Personal -> Certificates
- Right click the cert, All Tasks, Request Certificate with New Key
- Remove old cert